# Images hosted on imgur from posts are rotting

Tags: support, images

I thought the images posted via the upload tool when creating a question/answer were immune to 'rotting' after so long, but this doesn't seem to be the case at: [How do I redirect these water currents to get my loot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/23023/2)

I vaguely recall there being some difference between `i.stack.imgur.com` and non-`stack` images, but these ones are `.stack.`

Comment: I fixed this one case, but I'm afraid this is really out of our hands.

Comment: @badp, how'd you fix it?  Just removed the `stack` subdomain?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Answer (score 9):

This may not be a case of image rot, as it were. However, it is something people have to be mindful of and see to its fixing whenever they run into it.

When we setup the i.stack address, we subsequently performed a global replace of all imgur URLs that were provided after a specific date. This affected even the ones which weren't uploaded through Stack Exchange, which means they don't actually have a corresponding i.stack image. This is going to be the most likely cause of any broken images with the i.stack address provided.

The proper fix would be to not revert the link back to the non-i.stack, but to re-upload the non-i.stack image through the Stack Exchange UI so that we will have a persistent copy.

See also: [a relevant Meta Stack Overflow post on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101028/imgur-images-are-redisappearing-again)

Comment: Why though? What are the advantages of `i.stack.` as opposed to just `i.`?

Comment: @Arda Images hosted at i.stack aren't subject to the imgur policy of "If it doesn't get viewed often, it gets taken down". I also think there's some measure of greater stability (in that imgur going down will not kill off all the images on our sites), but don't quote me on that bit.

Comment: "I also can confirm there's some measure of greater stability (in that imgur going down will not kill off all the images on our sites)" -- Grace Note.

Comment: When I noticed this (one of my answers was affected), I used the search and SEDE to find and fix a dozen or so posts where this happened. This one must've slipped through, because searching for inline images is not possible AFAIK, and the SEDE data was a tad stale.

Comment: @lunboks You can use Google still.